# contenteditable span Alternative

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I am able to create a `contenteditable` span inside some text that grows and shrinks and can wrap multiple lines without taking up the entire width:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  padding: 5px;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span contenteditable="true">Type Something</span>
</div>
```

I am aware of the issues and challenges of `contenteditable` and I just want plain text. As such I would like to use an `<input type="text">` to accomplish this. Is there CSS/JS I can apply to make it behave like this without programmatically simulating it with multiple input fields?

## Clarification

A `textarea` is `display: inline-block` and making it inline doesn't truly make it inline like a span element, thus it is not the alternative I am looking  for

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this before and resorted to essentially re-inventing textarea with div's for each line and a span for the cursor and some other styling.

Here's the basic idea:

```js
let $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
let text = 'Type Soemthing';
let cursor = text.length;

let updateDisplay = () => {
  $('#pre-text').textContent = text.substr(0, cursor);
  $('#post-text').textContent = text.substr(cursor);
};

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  switch (e.key) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      cursor--;
      break;  
    case 'ArrowRight':
      cursor++;
      break;  
    case 'Backspace':
      text = text.substr(0, cursor - 1) + text.substr(cursor);
      cursor--;
      break;
    case 'Delete':
      text = text.substr(0, cursor) + text.substr(cursor + 1);
      break;
    default:
      if (e.key.length === 1) {
        text = text.substr(0, cursor) + e.key + text.substr(cursor);
        cursor++;
      }
  }
  updateDisplay();
});

updateDisplay();
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 5px;
}

span#cursor {
  background: #000;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="pre-text"></span>
  <span id="cursor"></span>
  <span id="post-text"></span>
</div>
```